# Worklight - 6.1 How to remove worklight.css file from index page in all enviornment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using worklight 6.1 version and building iPhone, android , windows phone environment.
Whenever I am deploying the environment it is adding worklight.css file with the environment in index.html file and adding some extra css in main.css file.

Issue is , these css is conflicting with my css files so just let me know how to avoid this or if can remove worklight.css file from index page.

Is there any solution for this.

Comment: if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot not-load worklight.css, as it is inject to the app during build time.
What you can do instead is override any CSS rules using [`!important`](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/).

For example:

```
body {
    background-color: red !important
}
```

What CSS does worklight.css contain that overrides your app's?
I know of only `background-color: white` being injected to the Android environment - you can override it with the above, and this is already fixed for a future release.

Comment: I've found this issue in MFP 7.0, too. Even worklight.css contains just a little seletor, it really overrides our stylesheet and makes it looks different between real devices and the simulator...

Comment: And fixed by change `body.wl_ios7{padding-top:15pt;}` to `body.wl_ios7{padding-top: 0 !important;}`